# Override value in different model using save function in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project where users can add cash to their account. As such i have two models, UserProfile which has basic info on the user (including their account balance), and Transaction to allow them to add cash. Is there any way to update the balance field in (UserProfile) when a trasnaction is submited?

Here is what my models.py looks like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user.balance = self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So basically I want to update the balance field in UserProfile to be the value entered in amount in the Transaction model. Anyone know how I cna accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example looks fine except for a single problem: you are missing the `save()` on the user profile:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user.balance = self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user.save()
```